# How to restrict tables under same section

Tags: tables, lyx, longtable

I have a problem in managing tables in LyX. Problem is that I need tables under the same section, but I could not. Can anybody help me in this regard?

Comment: Do you mean tables should not float out of their section, or something else? The question is not very clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect that you want to add

```
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
```

Then floating tables and figures will not float out of the section in which they are entered.

Comment: For any lost souls looking for other types of floats: this usage of `placeins` works just as well for figure-floats as well. I therefore suspect that this should work for all types of floats - not just table floats